# How to do background recording with front camera in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, background-process, android-video-record

I am building an Android app in Kotlin and I need to perform background recording using the front camera. I have searched online but could not find a solution specific to Kotlin. Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this using Kotlin? Thank you in advance!

## **Here is my code but for some reason it doesn't work**

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var startButton: Button
private lateinit var stopButton: Button
private val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE=1001
private val REQUEST_CAMERA_AND_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 1
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button)
    stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stop_button)

    // Request permissions for camera, record audio and write external storage
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    startButton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, VideoRecordService::class.java)
        startForegroundService(intent)
    }

    stopButton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, VideoRecordService::class.java)
        stopService(intent)
    }

}
```

}

class VideoRecordService : Service() {

```
private var camera: Camera? = null
private var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null
private var outputFile: File? = null
private val permissions = arrayOf(
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
)

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    startForeground(1, createNotification())
    startRecording()
    return START_STICKY
}

private fun createNotification(): Notification {
    val channelId = "VideoRecorder"
    val channelName = "Video Recorder"
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
    val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance)
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
    notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)

    return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setContentTitle("Recording video")
        .setContentText("Touch to open app")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build()
}

private fun startRecording() {
    camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)

    outputFile = getOutputFile()
    if (!outputFile!!.exists())
    {
        Log.e("VideoRecordService", "Output file does not exist")
        return
    }
    mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
        setCamera(camera)
        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT)
        setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT)
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT)
        setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT)
        setOutputFile(outputFile?.path)
        setPreviewDisplay(null)

        try {
            prepare()
            start()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}


private fun getOutputFile(): File? {
    val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
    Log.d("VideoRecordService", "Movies directory: $dir")
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        val created = dir.mkdirs()
        Log.d("VideoRecordService", "Movies directory created: $created")
    }
    val videoFile = "video_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4"
    val outputFile = File(dir, videoFile)
    Log.d("VideoRecordService", "Output file: $outputFile")
    return outputFile
}

private fun stopRecording() {
    if (mediaRecorder == null) return
    try {
        mediaRecorder?.stop()
        mediaRecorder?.reset()
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    mediaRecorder?.release()
    camera?.lock()

    saveVideoToGallery()

    Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

private fun saveVideoToGallery() {
    if (outputFile == null) return
    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, outputFile?.name)
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, outputFile?.path)
    }
    val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
    contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        stopRecording()
    }
    camera?.release()
    camera = null

}
```

}